# Busca de endereço no google maps

Tags: google-maps

Tenho que colocar no meu site uma busca de endereços onde o usuário digita o endereço e mostra o lugar digitado e o endereço do site.

Como fazê-lo?

Answer (score 1):

Use o serviço de [Geocoding](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/geocoding-simple) da API do Google Maps para isso.

Veja o exemplo de implementação deles, é bem fácil de entender:

```
function initMap() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 8,
    center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644}
  });
  var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

  document.getElementById('submit').addEventListener('click', function() {
    geocodeAddress(geocoder, map);
  });
}

function geocodeAddress(geocoder, resultsMap) {
  var address = document.getElementById('address').value;
  geocoder.geocode({'address': address}, function(results, status) {
    if (status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
      resultsMap.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: resultsMap,
        position: results[0].geometry.location
      });
    } else {
      alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Poxa obrigada !!

Comment: De nada! Se a resposta resolveu seu problema, valide-a com um ok. :)